# Issue with IEnumerable, Where, and Object.ReferenceEquals

Tags: c#, .net-core, ienumerable, .net-core-3.0

Trying to solve an Exercism problem (Dominoes). In this problem I am attempting to create a valid chain of dominoes such that numbers are touching each other and the first and last number are the same.

Example: `[1|2], [3,1], [3,2] -> [1|2][2|3][3|1]`

I am using brute force to try all combinations. To do so I start a chain with all possible combinations using the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class Dominoes
{
    private class Domino
    {
        public readonly int First;
        public readonly int Last;

        public Domino(int first, int last)
        {
            First = first;
            Last = last;
        }

        public Domino Flip() => new Domino(Last, First);
    }

    private class Chain
    {
        private readonly List<Domino> chained = new List<Domino>();

        private readonly List<Domino> remaining = new List<Domino>();

        private int First => chained[0].First;

        private int Last => chained[chained.Count - 1].Last;

        public bool Complete => remaining.Count == 0 && First == Last;

        private Chain(Domino domino, IEnumerable<Domino> remaining, IEnumerable<Domino> chained = null)
        {
            if (chained != null)
            {
                this.chained.AddRange(chained);
            }

            this.chained.Add(domino);

            this.remaining.AddRange(remaining);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<Chain> Start(IEnumerable<Domino> dominoes)
        {
            var chains = new List<Chain>();

            foreach (var domino in dominoes)
            {
                var remaining = dominoes.Where(d => d != domino);

                chains.Add(new Chain(domino, remaining));
                chains.Add(new Chain(domino.Flip(), remaining));
            }

            return chains;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Chain> Extend()
        {
            var chains = new List<Chain>();

            foreach (var domino in this.remaining)
            {
                var remaining = this.remaining.Where(d => d != domino);

                if (domino.First == Last)
                {
                    chains.Add(new Chain(domino, remaining, chained));
                }

                if (domino.Last == Last)
                {
                    chains.Add(new Chain(domino.Flip(), remaining, chained));
                }
            }

            return chains;
        }
    }

    public static bool CanChain(IEnumerable<(int, int)> dominoes)
    {
        var chains = Chain.Start(dominoes.Select(d => new Domino(d.Item1, d.Item2)));

        return chains.Any() ? Iterate(chains) : true;
    }

    private static bool Iterate(IEnumerable<Chain> chains)
    {
        var newChains = new List<Chain>();

        foreach (var chain in chains)
        {
            if (chain.Complete) return true;

            newChains.AddRange(chain.Extend());
        }

        if (newChains.Count == 0) return false;

        return Iterate(newChains);
    }
}
```

Test Code

```
using System;
using Xunit;

public class DominoesTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Singleton_that_cant_be_chained()
    {
        var dominoes = new[] { (1, 2) };
        Assert.False(Dominoes.CanChain(dominoes));
    }
}
```

Run using `dotnet test`

The filtering for `remaining` in `Chain.Start` does not appear to work.

Example (using `new [] { (1, 2) }` as input for `CanChain`)

```
# Expected: `Chain: [1|2] Remaining:`
# Actual:   `Chain: [1|2] Remaining: [1|2]`
```

If I call `.ToList()` on the `dominoes.Select(d => new Domino(d))` in `CanChain` it starts working.

EDIT: added more information

Comment: Is Domino defined as a class or a struct?

Comment: `object.ReferenceEquals` is only required if the class (Domino in this case) has overloaded its `==`, which seems unlikely. It would really help if you'd show the `Domino` code.

Comment: Agreed that `Object.Reference` is not required.

Added the `Domino` code

Comment: The source code for Iterate is required to reproduce.

Comment: Added remaining source

Comment: Could you post a tiny bit more code?  Something we can copy and run to produce the unexpected result.  Would be easier to just debug this.

Comment: When I run it and pass in a single domino, `remaining` comes up empty as expected.

Comment: I'm running this in `.NET Core App 3.0`, have not tried on `.NET Framework`

Comment: @SinaHoseinkhani `dominoes.Select` is a Linq method that returns `IEnumerable<Domino>`

Comment: Reproduced. (.Net Core 3.0.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the enumeration of `Select` is not executed right away, but instead is delayed. This means that each time you are accessing/using the `IEnumerable<>` returned by the `Select()` method you will get a new fresh list. But this also means you are creating new `Domino` objects all the time. And as you are not overwriting the `Equals()` method each of these `Domino` object will be different, even if they have the same values.

To show the problem check the following code:

```
private class Foobar {
    private readonly int value;

    public Foobar(int v) {
        Console.WriteLine("## CONSTRUCTOR ## Foobar object created with value: "+v);
        this.value = v;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return "Foobar("+this.value+")";
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args) {
    int[] numbers = new [] { 1, 5};
    IEnumerable<Foobar> range = numbers.Select(i => new Foobar(i));

    Console.WriteLine(range.Count());
    foreach (Foobar entry in range) {
        Console.WriteLine("Build an enumerable without "+entry);
        IEnumerable<Foobar> remaining = range.Where(it => it != entry);
        Console.WriteLine("The length of the remaining: "+remaining.Count());
        foreach (Foobar remainingEntry in remaining) {
            Console.WriteLine("Entry of remaining: "+remainingEntry);
        }
    }
}
```

When you run this code you will get the following output:

```
## CONSTRUCTOR ## Foobar object created with value: 1
## CONSTRUCTOR ## Foobar object created with value: 5
2
## CONSTRUCTOR ## Foobar object created with value: 1
Build an enumerable without Foobar(1)
## CONSTRUCTOR ## Foobar object created with value: 1
## CONSTRUCTOR ## Foobar object created with value: 5
The length of the remaining: 2
## CONSTRUCTOR ## Foobar object created with value: 1
Entry of remaining: Foobar(1)
## CONSTRUCTOR ## Foobar object created with value: 5
Entry of remaining: Foobar(5)
## CONSTRUCTOR ## Foobar object created with value: 5
Build an enumerable without Foobar(5)
## CONSTRUCTOR ## Foobar object created with value: 1
## CONSTRUCTOR ## Foobar object created with value: 5
The length of the remaining: 2
## CONSTRUCTOR ## Foobar object created with value: 1
Entry of remaining: Foobar(1)
## CONSTRUCTOR ## Foobar object created with value: 5
Entry of remaining: Foobar(5)
```

As you see the constructor is called **way too often**. Each time someone use the `IEnumerable` from the `Select()` call it will generate the enumerable list again so it doesn't interfere with other parallel running iterations on the same data. However, since you create new objects inside your `Select()` statement you will get new objects for each creation of the `IEnumerable` of `Select()`.

As you have already noticed, to solve the problem you use something like `ToList()` and to evaluate/create the `Domino` objects once. With one `ToList()` call the output changes as follow:

```
## CONSTRUCTOR ## Foobar object created with value: 1
## CONSTRUCTOR ## Foobar object created with value: 5
2
Build an enumerable without Foobar(1)
The length of the remaining: 1
Entry of remaining: Foobar(5)
Build an enumerable without Foobar(5)
The length of the remaining: 1
Entry of remaining: Foobar(1)
```

You see, only two objects are created and the `!=` will work as expected, since there are only these two objects.

Comment: I figured it would be something along those lines.